# QGIS's "setItemPosition" doesn't seem to work for QgsComposerLabel

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I'm using QGIS 2.18 and I'm printing maps using a QGIS plugin I made myself. The method `setItemPosition(x, y)` is working fine with my legend (`QgsComposerLegend` object).

But when I try to use the same method `setItemPosition(x, y)` with a piece of text (`QgsComposerLabel`object), it doesn't do anything and my text remains in the upper left corner of the composition :

[image]

As you can see above, all my 5 labels are stuck in the upper left corner of the picture, while my idea was to put the 5 labels in 5 different places, using a `for` loop in Python.

Additional relevant info :

- My paper size is (260, 200)
- I used `label.setItemPosition(150, 50)` as a test, so the labels should be placed around the middle of the picture.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to the latest LTR?

Comment: @Erik unfortunately my company is using a lot of QGIS 2 plugins, some of which proved not to be compatible with QGIS 3, which is why I'm sticking to QGIS 2